# SQL compare rows with displaying differences in columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, rows

Hello im looking for a query in SQL or MySQl about comparing rows in the same table

That query should display 2 last rows with the same id's but with different records in columns

My Table

```
ID|is_superuser|username|first_name|last_name|email          |is_staff|is_active|
 1|           1|admin   |FC        |         |admin@admin.com|       1|        1|
 1|           1|admin   |          |         |admin@admin.com|       1|        1|
 1|           1|admin   |adminname |         |admin@admin.eu |       1|        1|
```

RESULT :

```
ID|username|first_name|email|
 1|admin   |adminname |admin@admin.eu|
 1|admin   |          |admin@admin.com|
```

THX For Help

Comment: Can you add create and insert statements for table in post?

Comment: I don't understand the logic by which you end up with those two out of three particular records.  All three records have the same timestamp.

Comment: The result should display ID|USERNAME + columns with differences between two last rows

Comment: I want make a history module with all log changes . This query may easily compare two rows with the same ID

Comment: Can you add few more records to your sample data set, It will help to get clear idea about the logic? Is like that you want to compare ID records having same last Login in all records & date joined for all of them?

Comment: np, I will edit that to clearly logic about my question

Comment: Ok i edited post

Comment: If rows have the same records in column they should be skipped (except ID and username).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `exists` clause to demand that there is another row with the same `id` but a different `email`:

```
select  *
from    MyTable t1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    MyTable t2
        where   t1.id = t2.id
                and coalesce(t1.email, '') <> coalesce(t2.email, '')
        )
```

Per your comment, if you have many columns, you can generate the `where` clause with a query like:

```
select  concat('and coalesce(t1.', column_name, ', '''') <> coalesce(t2.', 
               column_name, ', '''')')
from    information_schema.columns
where   table_name = 'MyTable'
```

Comment: yes but i have 200 columns, i need to show differences between two logs so i do not know which columns are changed

Comment: You could generate the `where` clause, example added